# Iterate over range with given first and last iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I got a piece of code like this:

```
template<class Iter>
void printRange(Iter begin, Iter last) {
    for (Iter i = begin; i != last; i++) {
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
    }
     outstd::cout << *last << ", ";
}
```

My question is: how can i print out the last element, too, elegantly? Couting the last element individually after the loop does not seem to be a nice and correct solution, ... Is there a better way? Note that i cannot use the <= operator or boost or any stl specific feature either.

Comment: Usually, the "last" iterator really points to *past* the last element, so your code will work and print out every element just fine. Are you sure that `last` points to a valid element too?

Comment: Yes, actually this not my code, i just try to use/modify it. If it was the *past last*, i would call it *end*, anyway.

Comment: @jalf, I had the same issue when you find both your iterators with "find" and you want to print all between them with them.

Comment: This is a badly spec'd function, for two reasons.  One, it's name doesn't make sense, because it doesn't print containers, it prints ranges.  And two, it doesn't follow the well established and respected tradition of accepting a half-open range.  So, why are you using it?

Comment: Because this family of functions uses array to, and get called like `printRange(testArray, testArray + n-1)`. I sorry if the name was misleading i edited it in a hurry. Secondly, this is not my code. :)

Comment: What's wrong with `printContainer(testArray, testArray + n);` ?  It's less typing.  You can do the same thing with standard library algorithms.  In fact, the STL was specifically designed to be backwards compatible with arrays and pointers.

Comment: You are right. As i already stated, this is not my code, and this code have to be work w/ the other calls, like the one in my previous posts. But i cannot agree more w/ everyone, i would use [first, end) iterators for this.

Comment: I understand it's not your code, my question was why you are using it?

Comment: In that case, can't you simply increment the `last` iterator`, making it an "end" iterator?

Comment: Yeah, that's the simplest answer (and the accepted answer does this, too), idk why i did not do that.

@BenjaminLindley I just modified it. I won't use it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the separator conditionally:

```
template<class Iter>
void printContainer(Iter first, Iter last) {
    for (Iter i = first, end = ++last; i != end; i++) {
        std::cout << (i == first ? "" : ", ") << *i;
    }
}
```

For a more standard `[begin, end)` half-open range:

```
template<class Iter>
void printContainer(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (Iter i = begin; i != end; i++) {
        std::cout << (i == begin ? "" : ", ") << *i;
    }
}
```

Comment: As i already stated in my OP, this is called with the real *last* element, and not the *end*. But this would be the better solution, i agree.

Comment: @WonderCsabo ah, OK.  I've added both solutions.

Answer (score 4):

For the STL container classes, the iterator value *end* is *after* the last item. Once *end* is reached, it can quit, because all items have been handled.

Answer (score 0):

In The STL, there is a last iterator that does not hold a value, so your loop would work in this case.

Maybe you should consider adding another iterator at the end of your list that does not contain any value, so you would be consistent with the STL.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
template<class Iter>
void printContainer(Iter begin, Iter last) {
    Iter afterEnd = end;
    afterEnd++;
    for (Iter i = begin; i != afterEnd; i++) {
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
    }
     outstd::cout << *last << ", ";
}
```

but notice that if `end` was given by STL libs (like `list.end()`) it's already a value after the last element, and `++` will throw an exception.

so I would use the code you have in the way you have it. but when I was calling it I pass it the value after the last value I want to print.